# What unit test case to be performed for this method

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

I am new to .Net field and i wrote a method in c# which takes a string as a parameter from the data base and returns a BusinessContact type which consists entityid, contactid, name, alias.
Here is my code

```
public BusinessContact GetAccountExecutiveForBroker(string brokerUserName)
{
    SqlStatement select = new SqlStatement();
    select.Sql = @"select cb.* from custom_brokers cb 
                    join rolodex_contacts rc on cb.aecontactid = rc.contactid and cb.lenderdatabaseid = rc.lenderdatabaseid
                    where cb.brokerusername = @brokerUserName";
    select.AddParameter("brokerusername", brokerUserName);
    return db.SelectObject(select, MapContact);
}
```

I am unable to figure out what unit test cases can be performed on this method. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can test input parameter brokerUserName.

- if it is empty.
- if it is null
- if it contains sql injection data (like 'a' or 1=1 --;)